# PhoneGap Build Permissions

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have

```
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

in my config.xml but my Android device still shows all (full) permissions as being requested upon install. How can I figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the following tag to your `config.xml`.

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

You will still have the **INTERNET** permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires. Remaining preferences you can remove if you dont want.

Referenced from here [**Phonegap Build Docs**](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)

If its still giving you problems follow this [**Link**](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/config_xml_disable_all_permissions_not_working_android)

Comment: Links are nolonger valid.